# Am I wrong in thinking it is isomorphism rather than homomorphism?

Tags: commutative-algebra

The following is a quotation from the proof of Proposition 11.10 in 
"Introduction to Commutative Algebra" by Atiyah and MacDonald.

Also if ${\mathfrak m}'$ is the maximal ideal of $A'$, 
**$A'/{\mathfrak m}'^n$ is a homomorphic image of $A/{\mathfrak m}^n$,
hence $l(A/{\mathfrak m}^n) \geq l(A'/{\mathfrak m}'^n)$.**

In the above,
$A$ is a Noetherian local ring, ${\mathfrak m}$ is its maximal ideal, 
and $A'=A/{\mathfrak p}_0$ where ${\mathfrak p}_0$ is a prime ideal in $A$.
Also, $l(M)$ is the length of $M$.

It seems to me that 
**$A'/{\mathfrak m}'^n$ is an isomorphic image of $A/{\mathfrak m}^n$, 
hence $l(A/{\mathfrak m}^n) = l(A'/{\mathfrak m}'^n)$.**

Am I wrong ?

Comment: Without looking at whether you're right to say that $A'/{\mathfrak m}'^n$ is an isomorphic image of $A/{\mathfrak m}^n$, or whether you're right to say that $l(A/{\mathfrak m}^n) = l(A'/{\mathfrak m}'^n)$, one can say that _if_ those are right, then $A'/{\mathfrak m}'^n$ is a homomorphic image of $A/{\mathfrak m}^n$ and $l(A/{\mathfrak m}^n) \ge l(A'/{\mathfrak m}'^n)$, since every isomorphism is a homomorphism, and generally if $x=y$ then $x\ge y$.

Comment: That still leaves your question intact, except for the words "rather than" in the title.  "Am I right in thinking this homomorphism is an isomorphism" might fit better.

Comment: Take $\mathfrak m^2\not=\mathfrak m=\mathfrak p_0, n=2$.

Comment: Dear Pierre-Yves, if you upgraded that nice but extremely concise suggestion to an answer (with an example, maybe) , I'd be glad to upvote you and I hope other users would do the same.

Comment: Dear @Georges: Thank you very much! (By the way, you forgot the `@` sign...)

Comment: Dear @Pierre-Yves: True, I often forget that @ sign...

Comment: @Georges: That's the only imperfection I've been able to find so far in your personality...

Comment: Thank you @MichaelHardy for your comment.

Answer (score 3):

The natural epimorphism from $A/\mathfrak m^n$ to $A'/\mathfrak m'^n$ is **not** injective in general.

Indeed, if you put 
$$
A:=\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z,\quad\mathfrak p_0=\mathfrak m=(2),\quad n=2, 
$$ 
you get 
$$
A'=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z,\quad\mathfrak m'^n=\mathfrak m'^2=\mathfrak m'=0,\quad A'/\mathfrak m'^n=\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z, 
$$ 
$$
\mathfrak m^n=\mathfrak m^2=0,\quad A/\mathfrak m^n=A=\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z. 
$$ 
Thus $A/\mathfrak m^n$ has four elements, whereas $A'/\mathfrak m'^n$ has only two elements.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. If ${\mathfrak p}_0={\mathfrak m}$, we have $A'/{\mathfrak m}'^n=A'=A/{\mathfrak m}$. So, the kernel of the mapping $A \rightarrow A'/{\mathfrak m}'^n$ is ${\mathfrak m}$ not ${\mathfrak m}^n$. Do you think that this is the only case when the mapping has the kernel other than ${\mathfrak m}^n$ ?

Comment: Dear @Aki: You're welcome. The kernel is $$\frac{\mathfrak p+\mathfrak m^n}{\mathfrak m^n}\simeq\frac{\mathfrak p}{\mathfrak p\cap\mathfrak m^n}\quad.$$ If you take $\mathfrak p=\mathfrak m^2$, $n=3$, you get $\mathfrak m^2/\mathfrak m^3$, which is nonzero in general. The map is injective iff $\mathfrak p\subset \mathfrak m^n$.

Comment: Thank you @Pierre-Yves. This time I fully understand.